# Classification of fibrations $\Bbb S^k\longrightarrow\Bbb S^d\longrightarrow B$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, differential-topology, topological-groups

Does there exist a complete classification of all fiber bundles $\Bbb S^k\longrightarrow\Bbb S^d\longrightarrow B$, that is, fibrations of $\smash{\Bbb S^d}$ with each fiber homeomorphic to $\smash{\Bbb S^k}$ for some fixed $k\le d$.

The [Wikipedia page on Hopf fibrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration#Generalizations) contains a list of some real/complex/quaternionic/octonionic fibrations.
In other words: is this list complete?

I am then interested, which of the base spaces $B$ that appear in above classification admit a topological/Lie group structure (compatible with its present topology).

---

**Update**

The last part of my question about topological/Lie group structure (which should have been a separate question from the start) was partially answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3421788/415941). The projective spaces listed there are exactly the base spaces of sphere fibrations *by great spheres* (according to ["On fibrations with flat fibres" by Ovsienko and Tabachnikov](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00864643/document)). It says nothing about the general case, though.

Comment: A related reference is Ovsienko-Tabachnikov article on Hopf Fibrations and
Hurwitz-Radon
Numbers (http://ovsienko.perso.math.cnrs.fr/Publis/Hopf1.pdf).

Comment: This story is relevant to the study of the Blaschke conjecture in Riemannian geometry, as it provides some of the topological restrictions on Blaschke manifolds.

Comment: @F.C. Thank you for hinting me to this very well written article! It seems to answer my question for the most part. Footnote 5 of this article reads "The next step would be a classification of affine Hopf fibrations. See [10, 19] for partial results. [...]". This suggests that the full question is still open. It turned out that I am actually already satisfied with a classification of fibrations by *great circles*, and this was achieved according to the paper "On fibrations with flat fibres.", also by Ovsienko and Tabachnikov. These are exactly the Hopf fibrations also found on Wikipedia.

Comment: On whether $B$ can admit a topological group structure, the answer is no. In fact, $B$ is not even an H-space. Indeed, theorem 6.10 in [Browder, W., Torsion in H-spaces. Ann. of Math. (2) 74 (1961), 24–51] says that if an H-space has finitely generated cohomology that vanish is all large degrees, then the first nonzero homotopy group of the space occurs in odd dimension. But $S^8$, $CP^m$, and homology $HP^m$ do not have this property. By Hurewicz theorem, their first nonzero homotopy groups occurs in degrees 8, 2, 4 respectively.

Comment: What you linked to at stackexchange answers neither your question there, nor the one here, because in your case $B$ is simply-connected so that it equals to its universal cover.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek I do not understand. The projective spaces for which the question at Math.SE was asked for are exactly the base spaces from above, as stated in "On fibrations with flat fibres" by Ovsienko and Tabachnikov, at least when we restrict to fibrations by great spheres.

Comment: I don't know what claim of Ovsienko-Tabachnikov you are referring to. In any case theirs is an expository article, i.e. not a primary reference with all proofs. In your question above you do not assume that the fibers are "great spheres".

Comment: @IgorBelegradek I refer to the first paragraph of the linked paper. Yes, I do not ask for fibrations by great circles. But, I said in a comment that this was my actual intention. I am not changing the question now, since it seems to be (more) interesting as it is, and it has attracted a good answer (I do not fully understand it though, as this is not my field). I edited the "Update" insofar as I now talk about a "*partial* answer" which is more than satisfying for *me*. And without further explanation I do not understand how it is wrong.

Comment: The first paragraph in the linked paper says nothing on the matter. In my view the ideal answer is the one that gives a proof or an explicit reference to one.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek I am honestly asking for your opinion: do you think that the linked article (more precisely: its first paragraph) at least claims that the projective spaces listed in the linked SE question are exactly the base spaces of spherical fibrations by great spheres? Because I do think so, and cannot understand how it can be interpreted otherwise. Do you further think that the answer by Neil is worth accepting. I feel not competent to judge its correctness.

Comment: Oh, apparently I looked at the version linked by F.C. whose first paragraph differs from the one you linked to which is why I was confused. In any case my point is very simple: The linked article of Ovsienko-Tabachnikov is not a reference for the fact that any fiber bundle with great sphere fibers is Hopf.  Their article may contain such a reference but I do not immediately see it. On the other hand, the two articles by Browder I mentioned in comments do provide a reference (for a stronger claim).

Answer (score 13):

I'll assume that $1\leq k<d$, the other cases being easy.  Then the long exact sequence of homotopy groups shows that $B$ is simply connected, so we have a Serre spectral sequence with untwisted coefficients:
$$ E_2^{ij} = H^i(B)\otimes H^j(S^k) \Longrightarrow H^{i+j}(S^d), $$ 
with $d_r\colon E_r^{ij}\to E_r^{i+r,j-r+1}$.  Let $u$ and $v$ be the generators of $H^k(S^k)$ and $H^d(S^d)$.  The only possible differential is $d_{k+1}\colon H^i(B)u\to H^{i+k+1}(B)$, and this is has the form $au\mapsto ax$ for some $x\in H^{k+1}(B)$.  The only way the spectral sequence can converge to $H^*(S^d)$ is if $k$ is odd and $H^*(B)=\mathbb{Z}[x]/x^{r+1}$ with $(r+1)(k+1)=v+1$.  We can now apply Adams's theorem on elements of Hopf invariant one to the first attaching map in $B$ to see that $k\in\{1,3,7\}$.  I think that there is an argument along similar lines that if $k=7$ we can only have $r\leq 2$, but I don't remember details.  Thus, your fibration looks cohomologically like one of the standard fibrations $S^1\to S^{2r+1}\to \mathbb{C}P^r$ or $S^3\to S^{4r+3}\to \mathbb{H}P^r$ or $S^7\to S^{8r+1}\to\mathbb{O}P^r$.   For the case $k=1$ we can use $[X,\mathbb{C}P^\infty]=H^2(X)$ to get a map $B\to\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ and check that it restricts to give a homotopy equivalence $B\to\mathbb{C}P^r$.  In the other cases I think it is also true that $B$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{H}P^r$ or $\mathbb{O}P^r$, but the argument is more complicated and again I do not remember details. [UPDATE: See comment below from Igor Belegradek: this last sentence is apparently wrong.]

Comment: The original reference is [Browder, William, Higher torsion in H-spaces, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 108 (1963), 353–375] where it is shown that the fiber must be $S^1, S^7, S^3$ in which cases the respective bases are homotopy $CP^m$, $S^8$, and (I think) the rational homology $HP^m$. There are some examples in the last case which aren't homotopy $HP^m$.

Comment: If $d < k$ it seems like you get $H^*(B) = \mathbb{Z}[x,y]/y^2$ where $|x| = k+1$ and $|y| = d$. It seems like there could be nontrivial examples of this? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @KevinCasto we are assuming that we have an actual fibre bundle rather than just a fibration, so $B$ will have dimension $d-k$ and so cannot have cohomology in degrees above that.

Comment: @NeilStrickland Fair enough! I do think the fibration question is interesting though. e.g., is there a fibration $S^3 \to S^d \to B$, where $H^*(B) = H^*(S^d \times \mathbb{H}P^\infty)$?

Comment: Oh duh, of course there is, because $\mathbb{H}P^\infty = BS^3$. Same with $S^1 \to S^d \to S^d \times \mathbb{C}P^\infty$

Comment: I think the Smale conjecture might imply that the foliation by $S^3$s is equivalent to a principle $SU(2)$ bundle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smale_conjecture  I'm not sure if this is helpful in a classification though.